# How to assign an application to specific NUMA node?

Tags: delphi

Following code only allows to change affinity in current NUMA node. Is there a function which would allow me to specify also NUMA node? I would prefer to avoid external solutions like `start /NODE 3 /AFFINITY 1 program.exe`

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var AffinityMask:Cardinal;
begin    
  AffinityMask:=1;
  SetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(),AffinityMask);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in Microsoft's [NUMA Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/numa-support) documentation:

> **First of all, you will need to determine the layout of nodes in the system.** To retrieve the highest numbered node in the system, use the `GetNumaHighestNodeNumber` function. Note that this number is not guaranteed to equal the total number of nodes in the system. Also, nodes with sequential numbers are not guaranteed to be close together. To retrieve the list of processors on the system, use the `GetProcessAffinityMask` function. You can determine the node for each processor in the list by using the `GetNumaProcessorNode` function. Alternatively, to retrieve a list of all processors in a node, use the `GetNumaNodeProcessorMask` function.
>
> After you have determined which processors belong to which nodes, you can optimize your application's performance. **To ensure that all threads for your process run on the same node, use the `SetProcessAffinityMask` function with a process affinity mask that specifies processors in the same node.** This increases the efficiency of applications whose threads need to access the same memory. Alternatively, to limit the number of threads on each node, use the `SetThreadAffinityMask` function.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like there is undocumented function called **NtSetInformationProcess**

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/e0f49cda-4cbf-4da0-918a-0568271edb9f/process-affinity-on-a-system-with-128-processors?forum=wdk

> I found an interesting API which is essentally what I want.
>
> The goal here was to do the same thing as SetProcessAffinityMask()
>   with groups.  As it turns out, there is such a function, but it is
>   undocumented.
>
> I discovered that NtSetProcessInformation() will set both the group
>   and affinity mask for an already running process.  It's API is
>   something like this:
>
> GROUP_AFFINITY group_affinity;
>
> group_affinity.group = 1;  // Second group of 64 processors
>
> group_affinity.mask = 0x0000FFFF00000000;
>
> NtSetProcessInformation (hProcess, 0x15, &group_affinity,
>   group_affinity_size)
>
> It works very well and is the same API that TaskManager uses to change
>   the affinity group and mask of processes.
>
> Of course, since it is undocumented, it is subject to change, so it is
>   best not to employ this in retail software.  I am using it only to run
>   performance tests in our lab, so no big problem here.

So here is my attempt to translate that code to Delphi7. Assign process to first cpu on first NUMA node.

```
function NtSetInformationProcess(HProcess: CARDINAL; ProcessInformationClass: BYTE; ProcessInformation: POINTER; ProcessInformationLength: CARDINAL): CARDINAL; stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll' name 'NtSetInformationProcess';

type
   TGROUP_AFFINITY = record
     group  : WORD;
     mask   : cardinal;
     Reserved: array [0..2] of WORD;
   end; 

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var group_affinity:TGROUP_AFFINITY;
    HRES: HRESULT;
begin

  group_affinity.group:= 0;
  group_affinity.mask:= 1;
  HRES:=NtSetInformationProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), $15 , @group_affinity, SizeOf(group_affinity));

  if HRES = S_OK then showmessage('OK') else showmessage('ERROR'); 

end;
```

**EDIT: NOW It Works! `Reserved: array [0..2] of WORD;` was missing in definition and `group  : WORD;` must be instead of `group  : cardinal;`**

**_GROUP_AFFINITY structure**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_group_affinity

**NtSetProcessInformation documentation**
https://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FProcess%2FNtSetInformationProcess.html

Comment: The thing you did wrong was to use an undocumented function. They are never guaranteed to work in the way you think they should work, and they may change in the next Windows update package.

Comment: Well, but your answer might make other people think it is okay to use undocumented features, which in the long run makes the entire Windows platform much more difficult to use for all users around the world. You are not the only human being on this planet, you know. I suggest you start reading The Old New Thing, maybe here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031223-00/?p=41373

Comment: Or here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060110-17/?p=32703

Comment: Or here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060109-27/?p=32723

Comment: Or here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051026-44/?p=33613/

Comment: I could continue, but you might get the general idea.

Comment: See my edit. Problem was in wrong definition in TGROUP_AFFINITY